# Fullscreen video in UIWebView interferes with UIViewController's input accessory view

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a view which I set up as input accessory view for view controller the following way:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var bottomPane: UIView!

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    return bottomPane
}
```

Everything works just fine until I try to view YouTube video in fullscreen mode (video is loaded in `UIWebView`). When video enters fullscreen mode, keyboard and my input accessory view disappear (which is normal, I guess), but when I exit fullscreen mode, they do not appear. If I keep the reference to `bottomPane` `weak`, it becomes `nil` and application crashes, if I change it to `strong`, input accessory view remains hidden until the keyboard appears next time.

Can anybody explain what's going on and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on.

When user interacts with `UIWebView`, it becomes first responder and `inputAccessoryView` provided by view controller disappears (no idea why behavior in this case is different from, say, `UITextField`). Subclassing `UIWebView` and overriding `inputAccessoryView` property does not work (never gets called). So I block interaction with `UIWebView` until user loads video.

```
private func displayVideo(URL: String) {        
    if let video = Video(videoURL: URL) {
        // load video in webView 
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    } else {
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

When user loads video, the only way to detect that user has entered/exited fullscreen mode is to listen to `UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification` and `UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification` and detect when our window loses/gains key status:

```
//in view controller:
private func windowDidBecomeKey(notification: NSNotification!) {
    let isCurrentWindow = (notification.object as! UIWindow) == view.window

    if isCurrentWindow {
        // this restores our inputAccessoryView
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

private func windowDidResignKey(notification: NSNotification!) {
    let isCurrentWindow = (notification.object as! UIWindow) == view.window

    if isCurrentWindow {
        // this hides our inputAccessoryView so that it does not obscure video
        resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

And, of course, since `inputAccessoryView` can be removed at some point, we should recreate it if needed:

```
//in view controller:
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    if view == nil {
        // load view here
    }

    return view
}
```